# D3.js nested onclick and event propagation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, onclick, event-bubbling, event-propagation

I'm working on a nested onclick button feature using D3.js. An onclick on one of the items in the first list bring up a second list of subitems specific to the item in the first list. 
The first level onclick buttons captures the right div , the 2nd level onclick buttons always capture the div a level above the right div. which is div.wpd3-131-6. I am thinking it is a bubbling issue, so I have tried inserting d3.event.stopPropagation() into different locations but to no avail.

Any javascript expert can shed some light?

```js
function bac_button(bac_array){
  var buttons = d3.select(".wpd3-131-6")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "bacterias_buttons")
        .selectAll("div")
        .data(bac_array)
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .text(function(c) {
          return c;
        });
  
    buttons.on("mousedown", function(c) { d3.event.stopPropagation(); })
  buttons
      .on("click", function(c) {
      d3.event.stopPropagation();
      d3.select(".bacterias_buttons")
      .selectAll("div")
      .transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("color", "white")
      .style("background", "tomato");

      d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("background", "dodgerblue")
      .style("color", "white");
      
    buttons.on("mouseout", function(c) { d3.event.stopPropagation(); })
    
      
      if(this['__data__'] !== undefined) {
        var bac = this.__data__;
        select_countries_again (bac);
      }
      
      var anti_array = [];
      for (var k=0; k< [nested][0].length; k++ ) { //to get the index number of the bacteria bring clicked
        if (([nested][0][k].key) === bac) { 
          var p = k;
          var k = [nested][0].length + 1;
        }
        if (p >=0){
          for (var q = 0; q < [nested][0][p].values.length; q++ ){ // to get the antibiotics of the clicked bacteria from the index number obtained above
            var antiX = [nested][0][p].values[q].key;
            anti_array.push(antiX);
          }
        }
      } 
      var anti_memory = anti_array;
      anti_button (anti_memory);
      
      function anti_button(anti_memory){
      
        var anti_buttons = d3.selectAll(".antibiotics_buttons").remove();
        var anti_buttons = d3.select(".wpd3-131-6")
          anti_buttons.append("div")
          .attr("class", "antibiotics_buttons")
          .selectAll("div")
          .data(anti_array)
          .enter()
          .append("div")
          .text(function(ev) {return ev;});
          anti_buttons.on("mousedown", function(e) { d3.event.stopPropagation(); })
      
      anti_buttons.on("click", function(ev) { 
            d3.event.stopPropagation();
            d3.select(".antibiotics_buttons")
            .selectAll("div")
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("color", "white")
            .style("background", "orange");

            d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            //.style("background", "dodgerblue")
            .style("color", "white");
      anti_buttons.on("mouseout", function(e) { d3.event.stopPropagation(); })
            
          if(this['__data__'] !== undefined) {
          var bac = this.__data__;
          select_countries_again (bac, antiB);
          }
        });
      }
```